# how to get last li element using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get last `li` element of list . but it is not giving correct output. here is my markup

```
<div class="abc">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <ul><li>1.1</li><li>1.2</li></ul>
      <li>2</li>
       <ul><li>2.1</li><li>2.2</li></ul>
      <li>3</li>
        <ul><li>3.1</li><li>3.2</li></ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

trying like this

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.abc ul li:last-child').innerHTML)
```

**output Element**

```
<li>1.2</li>
```

**Expected output**

```
 <li>3</li>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid, and **must be fixed prior to any further actions**. `ul` can only have `li` children, not `ul` children. Why is the last list item not `<li>3.2</li>` for you?

Comment: Fix your markup. `<ul>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 problems

- Your HTML Is invalid as `ul` is not a valid child of `ul` so the nested ones need to be actually inside a `li`
- Use the `>` modifier to find direct descendents only in the selector

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.abc>ul>li:last-child').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <ul>
    <li>
      1
      <ul>
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      2
      <ul>
        <li>2.1</li>
        <li>2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      3
      <ul>
        <li>3.1</li>
        <li>3.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

If you do just want the text (and not the nested `ul`) you could put that text in a `span` and select that only

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.abc>ul>li:last-child span').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>2</span>
      <ul>
        <li>2.1</li>
        <li>2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>3</span>
      <ul>
        <li>3.1</li>
        <li>3.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

If you do just want the text (and not the nested `ul`) you could put that text in a `span` and select that only

Comment: Ups I had also  answered almost the same answer :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just go for the javascript way like this.

```
li = document.querySelectorAll('.abc>ul>li');
console.log(li[li.length-1].innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.abc ul li:last-child').innerHTML)
```

This syntax of giving `white space` instead of `adjacent selectors like ">"` is used when we want to apply common styles to multiple class.

So replacing your `whitespace` with **adjacent selectors like >**  will work in your case to select all its descendent childs.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.abc>ul>li:last-child').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <ul>
    <li>
      1
      <ul>
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      2
      <ul>
        <li>2.1</li>
        <li>2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      3
      <ul>
        <li>3.1</li>
        <li>3.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```